# 3rd party libraries not working if outside of index.html

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I downloaded some free html5 templates and will plan to use it on my angular2 program. The problem is when I put the body outside index.html or inside app.component.html, the template doesn't work. It displays nothing. I am sure that I put every src right. Take a look.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Angular QuickStart</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

    <!-- Facebook and Twitter integration -->
    <meta property="og:title" content=""/>
    <meta property="og:image" content=""/>
    <meta property="og:url" content=""/>
    <meta property="og:site_name" content=""/>
    <meta property="og:description" content=""/>
    <meta name="twitter:title" content="" />
    <meta name="twitter:image" content="" />
    <meta name="twitter:url" content="" />
      <meta name="twitter:card" content="" />

    <!-- Animate.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/animate.css">
    <!-- Icomoon Icon Fonts-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/icomoon.css">
    <!-- Bootstrap  -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.css">

    <!-- Flexslider  -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/flexslider.css">

    <!-- Owl Carousel  -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/owl.carousel.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/owl.theme.default.min.css">

    <!-- Theme style  -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">

    <!-- Modernizr JS -->
    <script src="assets/js/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
    <!-- FOR IE9 below -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

      <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>

    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>

    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <my-app></my-app>

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- jQuery Easing -->
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Waypoints -->
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Carousel -->
    <script src="assets/js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
    <!-- countTo -->
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.countTo.js"></script>
    <!-- Flexslider -->
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>
    <!-- Main -->
    <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Some code in app.component.html

```
<div id="fh5co-services" class="fh5co-bg-section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 text-center">
                <div class="feature-center animate-box" data-animate-effect="fadeIn">
                    <span class="icon">
                        <i class="icon-credit-card"></i>
                    </span>
                    <h3>Credit Card</h3>
                    <p>Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts. Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove</p>
                    <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-outline">Learn More</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 text-center">
                <div class="feature-center animate-box" data-animate-effect="fadeIn">
                    <span class="icon">
                        <i class="icon-wallet"></i>
                    </span>
                    <h3>Save Money</h3>
                    <p>Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts. Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove</p>
                    <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-outline">Learn More</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 text-center">
                <div class="feature-center animate-box" data-animate-effect="fadeIn">
                    <span class="icon">
                        <i class="icon-paper-plane"></i>
                    </span>
                    <h3>Free Delivery</h3>
                    <p>Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts. Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove</p>
                    <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-outline">Learn More</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Nothing is showing in here. The thing here is when I put everything in index.html, it works perfectly but when I start to get the code from the body tag and put it inside app.component.html, which I'm sure will go to  tag, it isn't showing up. My selector is correct and I'm sure of it. Anyone care to explain or give some solutions? That would be so much appreciated.

Comment: What's the problem? What do you expect to be shown? There is lots of code but I don't get what the relevant pieces are. Where is "outside index.html"?

Comment: Outside index.html means app.component.html or other html files. I put all the css requirements inside index.html and also all the required js files but the body needs to be on the other html files. Now, if I put all the code inside index.html file, it loads properly and as expected but when I remove all the contents of the body tag and put it inside the app.component.html, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jquery plugins don't work as expected on angular applications. Instead create a directive and put the code that you would normally have inside the link function of the directive.

There are a couple of points in the documentation that you could take a look at. You can find them here:

Ensure that when you are referencing the script in your view, you refer it last - after the angularjs library, controllers, services and filters are referenced.

Rather than using $(element), you can make use of angular.element(element) when using AngularJS with jQuery

[Refer this blog](https://amitgharat.wordpress.com/2013/02/03/an-approach-to-use-jquery-plugins-with-angularjs/)

Answer (score 0):

`<script>` tags are pruned from component templates (there is a pull request that allows them for some meta-data but that's not yet landed)

CSS files should be added to `@Component({ styleUrls: [...]})` and not to `<style>` tags in the template.